# How do I read this and return its tabular form?

Tags: python-3.x

Heyo smart peeps, I am tasked at my Co-Op with creating an app to automate data analysis and the text files they provide are a bit finicky. They claim they are in tabular form, and it looks like it, but my codes aren't working for some reason. Keep in mind that I am a novice, but I asked for a coding project because I know its something I need to learn. Anyways, below is a snippet of the top of the text file, and my simple, erroneous code. Thank you!

[image: text file data]

```
import numpy as np
filename = 'PS.prg1903-001_KSK_LB__0_00001.txt' 
data = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',', skiprows=1, dtype=str)

print(data)
```

This is the error message:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 6
```

Comment: You cannot read this file just by using a comma as a delimiter. I'm not sure why you even thought for a moment that would work. It is not tabular data either - I guess at best you could say parts of it is. To be honest, it is unlikely someone will write this code for you considering how little you have tried. But to have a chance, you must provide the data as text not as an image - because almost certainly nobody is going to hand write that data from a picture in order to create some solution for this.

Comment: Hey my bad man, I don't really know the ettiqute to this site; I hope I didn't seem like I was asking anybody to do all the work for me. I have set up the app part, but I thought for some reason that reading the data would be the easy part, thus why the code was a few lines here.

Comment: Also, I thought it was tabular data because you can copy/paste it into excel with no issues. Can you elaborate for a noobie? Thank you a bunch man

Comment: Hi Zane, why dont you start by posting your sample as text in your question instead of image, so we can at least copy & paste sample. More info regarding *what* data in that image needs to be clarified and what exactly `tabular` means in this context.